# What sort of levels are in the Lara Croft & GOL DLC?

Tags: lara-croft-the-guardian-of-light

What do the extra DLC levels in Lara Croft & GOL contain? I tried to search YouTube and all I found were puzzle levels without any enemies. Is it all there is to it - just some puzzles (only one puzzle level per DLC)?

Comment: serg - if you're still unsure be aware I've edited my answer below, should have a lot more information now to help you with the purchase decision.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the proud owner of all map packs (not the skin pack, though), I'd be happy to share :)

Basically, all packs contain three kinds of maps:

1. **Puzzle** maps - most similar to the skull tombs in the regular GOL (though in larger scale), you have to navigate a map that requires precise timing, careful jumping and some thinking. My favorite kinds of maps. No enemies appear in these maps.
2. Infinite **combat** maps - those maps feature infinite combat. You have a large map which starts out completely navigable and it has endlessly-respawning monsters, and the goal is to survive as long as you can. Personally it's my least favorite type of maps, but I have to admit some of these are cleverly designed - there's usually a lot of traps around to use against the monsters, strategic locations that offer some benefits but you cannot remain there indefinitely, etc.
3. What I call **"action"** maps - those are revisits of original campaign map concepts, though with some variations (sometimes a lot of variation). Basically they all revolve about trying to achieve something while constantly moving very fast :)

Here's a breakdown of the maps in each pack:

#### All the Trappings

- Double Crossing - puzzle
- Tooth and Nail - action (run over spikes)
- Temple Defense - combat
- Crushing expectations - action (balls destroy floor)

#### Things That Go Boom

- Ill Valley - combat
- Madness River - combat
- Mayan Mini-Golf - action (navigate a ball)
- Blast Rifts - puzzle

#### Hazardous Reunion

- Leglion's Lair - combat
- Puzzle Soup - puzzle
- Firefighters - combat
- Lava Chompy - action (chased by a monster)

Frankly I am not 100% happy with my purchase - I only really wanted the puzzle ones (though some of the action maps are also quite good). Still, the prices are very reasonable. It's worth noting that the maps are separate, meaning that (if I recall correctly) you don't have to complete the first to gain access to the 2nd, etc.

Answer (score 2):

As the name of the three DLCs suggest, they are either a character pack (unlocking new characters to play) or challenge packs (unlocking 4 new challenges each), so apart from challenges you don't get any new gameplay element.

Description of the DLCs from Steam:

Character Pack: Grab a friend or go at it alone as Kain and Raziel from the Legacy of Kain games. The two iconic characters must work together to defeat a new threat in an unfamiliar world.

Challenge Pack 1: Four new challenge maps filled with hordes of undead enemies and devious traps you must maneuver and exploit to survive.

Challenge Pack 2: Four new explosive challenge maps featuring a variety of tense puzzles, deadly traps, and relentless combat encounters.